# Does a vector change in length under the action of a rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Does a vector: $\overrightarrow{x} \in R^2$ change in length under the action of the rotation matrix: $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array} \right)$?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a vector stays the same under the action of a rotation matrix.

If $\overrightarrow{x} = (x_1,x_2)$, then the length of $\overrightarrow{x}$ is $|\overrightarrow{x}| = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$.

Now, what does the rotated vector look like? It is

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} x_2 \\ -x_1 \\ \end{array}\right).$$

The length of this vector is $\sqrt{x_2^2 + (-x_1)^2} = \sqrt{x_2^2+x_1^2} = |\overrightarrow{x}|$, so it is the same length as before.